# Ubuntu 19.04 can not install winehq-staging

Tags: wine, 19.04

How does one install `winehq-staging` on Ubuntu 19.04 given that winehq is full two days late on having a repository for disco dingo?

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ disco main'
Get:1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease [257 kB]
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease               
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu disco InRelease       
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu disco InRelease    
Ign:5 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu disco InRelease                 
Err:6 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu disco Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.122.217 443]
Hit:7 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease
Hit:8 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

stable version will work as expected, but if stagging is needed this is what I discovered, otherwise, I get unresolved dependency.

names and version do not match in the repository table, so for

Ubuntu 19.04 disco -> sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ cosmic main'

Ubuntu 18.04 bionic -> sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ xenial main'

Answer (score 3):

You can easily use the version for bionic (18.04.2) for the time until they have a release for it. To do so, you need to change the source list file accordingly.

I assume here you followed every other step mentioned on the [winehq page](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) you can do the following:

```
sudo sed -i.bak 's/disco/bionic/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine-staging.list
```

This will change the the source list file for wine-staging and creates a copy of the original file now ending with `.bak`. This should you enable to

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install wine-staging
```

on your computer. When they have released the version for wine on 19.04 (disco) you can simply remove the changed file, rename the old one back and then do an upgrade to the package:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine-staging.list
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine-staging.list.bak /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine-staging.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade wine-staging
```