# Ubuntu 19.04 install Wine Devel

Tags: wine, repository, development, 19.04

I saw another post where it was asked how to install Wine Staging on 19.04 since the repository has not been released yet.

I'm looking to install Wine Devel instead. I was not sure if it was enough to follow the instructions on the other post and change Staging with Devel or if the procedure would be different? The other post can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135335/ubuntu-19-04-can-not-install-winehq-staging#_=_). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for the 19.04 repository. You can still install PlayOnLinux and then install as many versions you want. It will install in /home/user/.PlayOnLinux/wine (and it keep the wine installed on your system).