# Cannot install Wine on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: wine, 19.04

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu and therefore to this forum so I am beforehand sorry for any mistake I might make.

I've followed the steps on https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu and the results are the following:

- Enabling 32 bit architecture works fine:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

- Downloading and adding the repository key works fine:

```
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
sudo apt-key add winehq.key
```

However, when trying to add the repository

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ disco main'
```

the console returns the following:

```
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                         
Hit:3 http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu artful InRelease                 
Ign:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/giact/winehq/ubuntu disco InRelease             
Hit:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Hit:7 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu disco InRelease                 
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ricotz/unstable/ubuntu disco InRelease          
Hit:9 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu cosmic InRelease     
Hit:11 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial InRelease         
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu disco InRelease
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu disco InRelease        
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu disco InRelease         
Err:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu disco Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu disco Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Ign:13 https://www.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu disco InRelease
Err:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu disco Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:19 https://www.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu disco Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 4.15.184.77 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

When trying to update, pretty similar results to the previous command are returned.

I've also tried everything on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135335/ubuntu-19-04-can-not-install-winehq-staging) post but nothing worked.

I hope someone can help me because I've been working on this all week long and still haven't managed to solve it.

Thank you all in advance.

**EDIT 1:**
sudo apt install wine won't help, nor fixing packages.

```
sudo apt install wine
```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine64 (>= 4.0.2-0ubuntu1~19.04~ricotz2) or
                 wine32 (>= 4.0.2-0ubuntu1~19.04~ricotz2)
        Depends: wine64 (< 4.0.2-0ubuntu1~19.04~ricotz2.1~) or
                 wine32 (< 4.0.2-0ubuntu1~19.04~ricotz2.1~)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt install -f
```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Why not run `sudo apt install wine` instead of all that?

Comment: Now it doesn't work when you install all a lot of different ppa. That broke the things. Remove all wine related ppa and it will install.

Answer (score 1):

> Why not run sudo apt install wine instead of all that?

That means you are needlessly overcomplicating things and shooting yourself in the foot.

If you simply had done nothing, i.e. not added the repo etc., a quick apt install wine would have done everything you need.

Instead you mucked up adding the repo and now it is explicitly complaining about that ("Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation...").

So what you should do is remove that repo, then run apt update and then just install wine.

Comment: There are many repos including `ricotz`  and some wine for `artful`, etc. It's a mess now.

Comment: Ok I  managed to do this and followed your comment but 

```Package 'wine' has no installation candidate```